# executing a stored procedure on a monthly schedule

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, trigger, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking to create an invoicing procedure that executes automatically once a month.   The procedure name is `INVOICE_PROC`.

I have tried to use a trigger to execute it but I can't get it to work. Would a trigger even be the best way to do this?

Comment: A trigger can do some action in response to some other action -- not what you need. You should look into dbms_scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle's [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm) to schedule a job to run monthly.